# Install/Enable archive engine in xampp

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am use `xampp` for `PHP - MySql` application in my windows PC, I want to use archive engine to save large data which is not use frequently but archive engine not shown in my `phpmyadmin` engine list.

I find lot on net but can't find solution for do the same.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to indicate which build of MySQL you are using and also add the output of the SHOW ENGINES command.

Comment: It is likely that you are using MariaDB with a Version greater than 10.1. If this is the case you have to activate the Plugin. `INSTALL SONAME 'ha_archive';`